# Import polygon area to CartoDB

Tags: carto

I would like to display some countries region on a map.  I have an CSV file with coordinates for each polygons (regions) as polygon; [[x,y],[x1,Y1],[xn,yn]].

When I import it to CartoDB, the_geom column = null and I have an invalid_the_geom column with coordinates.

Any ideas?

Comment: I think if you use csv CartoDB expects x,y only, ie, points, as there is no way to know that an arbitrary number of xy pairs is supposed to represent a polygons. Perhaps use GeoJSON or WKT instead.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I remember, CartoDB allows upload of geojson files. So open your csv in libre office calc or excel or wherever and concatenate it in this structure:

```
{
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"crs": { "type": "name", "properties": { "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84" } },
"features": [
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "value": 1234, "label": "polygon1" }, "geometry": { "type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ 10, 45 ], [ 11, 45 ], [ 11.8, 47.4 ] ] ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "value": 0815, "label": "polygon2" }, "geometry": { "type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ 1, 45 ], [ 9, 45 ], [ 10, 47 ] ] ] } }
]
}
```

As you can see, each polygon has its coordinate pairs in the end at

```
"type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [ [
```

save it as a geojson file like "file.geoJSON" and upload it as a new dataset to cartodb.

The above mentioned example is visible [here](https://geologyjobs.cartodb.com/viz/623723b0-cf63-11e5-8f54-0ecfd53eb7d3/public_map)